# How can i make a boat

Tags: activerobot, usv

I'm having an event for a boat race.Simple boat has to be made.All i have is 5 days.The restriction is 24V motor not more than 1000 rpm.What best material and shape will you suggest to make a boat.I know basic circuits.We have to make a boat with a wired circuit.That circuiting i can do but what can be an ideal shape for boat with maximum speed it can achieve?

Comment: Do you have a 24V motor that runs that slowly?  Typical DC motor RPMs are a lot higher than that, unless you use PWM to slow it down

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, but the maximum speed a boat can achieve is related to its length.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull_speed.  The longer the better.  The front and rear designs also have a large contribution to drag.  The pointier the better.  That's why crew racing boats are very long and pointy.  Boats with a flat stern (like a lot of speed boats) go fast because the boat planes at high speed (gets up on top of the water instead of plow through it).  So the flat back doesn't really affect them as much.

I am not sure if you will be able to make your model boat plane or not with those motor specs.  But i will also say that your prop also has a big part in the speed of the boat.  If you have the same motor, but with different props, the boat can have very different speeds.  Depending on the number, angle, and shape of the blades, the prop can be torqueier for slow speeds, or faster for higher speeds.  Kind of like a transmission after a motor.

Naval architecture is a large field, that i admittedly know very little about.  I only know some of these very high level concepts.  Hopefully these rules of thumb will help you out.